# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit support in Fabric Composer?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

In https://fabric-composer.github.io/start/quickstart.html it states that Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (64-bit) is supported (and Mac OS 10.12 too). Is 16.04 LTS 64-bit supported? If not, will be supported at some point in the future?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the question, The quickstart page (https://fabric-composer.github.io/start/quickstart.html) has been updated to include 16.04 LTS.